jMeter via Kotlin does not generate all properties
I am trying to generate jMeter JMX file using Kotlin and new jMeter functionality from v5.6.
But when I try to generate TestPlan like:
const val GUI_CLASS_VAL = "guiclass"

fun main() {
  // Initialize JMeter engine
  val jmeterHome = File("Apps/apache-jmeter-5.6.3")
  val jmeterProperties = File(jmeterHome, "bin/jmeter.properties")
  JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.path)
  JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.path)
  JMeterUtils.initLocale()

  ...
  // Test Plan
  val testPlan = TestPlan("Test Plan")

  // Test Plan HashTree
  val testPlanTree = ListedHashTree()
  testPlanTree.add(testPlan)
  ...

  // Save to JMX
  SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, FileOutputStream("test_plan.jmx"))
}

it generates something like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.3">
   <hashTree>
    <TestPlan testname="Test Plan">

but this file is not importable into jMeter
Problem loading XML from:'somePath/test_plan.jmx'. 
Cause:
IllegalArgumentException: guiclass attribute is not found

because it should look like this:
<TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan">

I was trying all stuff like testPlan.addParameter(GUI_CLASS_VAL, "TestPlanGui") or testPlan.setProperty(GUI_CLASS_VAL, "TestPlanGui") but none of it worked.
Is there any way how can I force the generator to include these properties properly to all elements?

What do you mean by "JMeter doesn't generate", it's you who supposed to provide respective values for TEST_CLASS and GUI_CLASS properties
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());

Otherwise you can use "Copy Code" context menu action, it sets the proper GUI_CLASS value

More information:

jmeter-from-code sample project
JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test
if you prefer Kotlin check out Building a Test Plan Programmatically


Thank you very much. These two lines is exactly what I was looking for
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan::class.java.name)
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui::class.java.name)
now it works perfectly.
